# Count the amount of times value A occurs with value B

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to count the amount of times a value in a Pandas dataframe occurs along with another value and count the amount of times for each row.

This is what I mean:

```
   a    t
0  a    2
1  b    4
2  c    2
3  g    2
4  b    3
5  a    2
6  b    3
```

Say I want to count the amount of times `a` occurs along with the number `2`, I'd like the result to be:

```
   a    t  freq
0  a    2  2
1  b    4  1
2  c    2  1
3  g    2  1
4  b    3  2
5  a    2  2
6  b    3  2
```

The `freq` (frequency) column here indicates the amount of times a value in column `a` appears along with a value in column `t`.

Please note that a solution that e.g. only counts the amount of times `a` occurs will result in a wrong frequency considering the size of my dataframe.

Is there a way to achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) or [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html):

```
df['freq'] = df.groupby(['a', 't'])['a'].transform('size')
#alternative solution
#df['freq'] = df.groupby(['a', 't'])['a'].transform('count')
print (df)
   a  t  freq
0  a  2     2
1  b  4     1
2  c  2     1
3  g  2     1
4  b  3     2
5  a  2     2
6  b  3     2
```