# Count the amount of times value A occurs without value B and vice versa

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do the opposite of the answer to this question (and in R not python).

[Count the amount of times value A occurs with value B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834225/count-the-amount-of-times-value-a-occurs-with-value-b)

Basically I have a dataframe with a lot of combinations of pairs of columns like so:

```
df <- data.frame(id1 = c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","4","4"),
                 id2 = c("2","2","3","4","1","3","4","1","4","2","1"))
```

I want to count, how often all the values in column A occur in the whole dataframe without the values from column B. So the results for this small example would be the output of:

```
df_result <- data.frame(id1 = c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","4","4"),
                        id2 = c("2","3","4","1","3","4","1","4","2","1"),
                        count = c("4","5","5","3","5","4","2","3","3","3"))
```

The important criteria for this, is that the final results dataframe is collapsed by the pairs (so in my example rows 1 and 2 are duplicates, and they are collapsed and summed by the total frequency 1 is observed without 2). For tallying the count of occurances, it's important that both columns are examined. I.e. order of columns doesn't matter for calculating the frequency - if column A has 1 and B has 2, this counts the same as if column A has 2 and B has 1.

I can do this very slowly by filtering for each pair, but it's not really feasible for my real data where I have many many different pairs.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `paste` the two id columns together to `id12` for later matching. Then use `sapply` to go through all rows to see the records where `id1` appears in `id12` but `id2` doesn't. `sum` that value and only output the `distinct` records. Finally, remove the `id12` column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(id12 = paste0(id1, id2),
              count = sapply(1:nrow(.), 
                             function(x) 
                               sum(grepl(id1[x], id12) & !grepl(id2[x], id12)))) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  select(-id12)
```

Or in base R completely:

```
id12 <- paste0(df$id1, df$id2)
df$count <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) sum(grepl(df$id1[x], id12) & !grepl(df$id2[x], id12)))
df <- df[!duplicated(df),]
```

#### Output

```
   id1 id2 count
1    1   2     4
2    1   3     5
3    1   4     5
4    2   1     3
5    2   3     5
6    2   4     4
7    3   1     2
8    3   4     3
9    4   2     3
10   4   1     3
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! I tested it on a subset of my data and it worked perfectly. It's still slowly running on my large dataset of 600000 rows ;) but it absolutely works.

Comment: If this is inappropriate for this medium, please let me know and I can ask a new question to reflect this info, but on my full data (~700000 rows), these solutions take a very large amount of time (>1.5 hours before I stopped the code from finishing). Do you have advice for optimizing this answer for speed?

Comment: @cebola Yes I think you can ask a new question aiming for efficiency. At the moment I don’t have any optimisation suggestion

Answer (score 1):

A full `tidyverse` version:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = paste(id1, id2),
         count = map(cur_group_rows(), ~ sum(str_detect(id, id1[.x]) & str_detect(id, id2[.x], negate = T))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient approach would be to work on a tabulation format:

```
tab = crossprod(table(rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), ncol(df)), c(df$id1, df$id2)))
#tab
#   
#    1 2 3 4
#  1 7 3 2 2
#  2 3 6 1 2
#  3 2 1 4 1
#  4 2 2 1 5
```

So, now, we have the times each value appears with another (irrespectively of their order in the two columns). Here on, we need a way to subset the above table by each pair and subtract the value of their cooccurence from the value of each id's total appearance.

Make a grid of all combinations:

```
gr = expand.grid(id1 = colnames(tab), id2 = rownames(tab), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Create 2-column matrices to subset the table:

```
id1.ij = cbind(match(gr$id1, colnames(tab)), 
               match(gr$id1, rownames(tab)))
id2.ij = cbind(match(gr$id1, colnames(tab)), 
               match(gr$id2, rownames(tab)))
```

Subtract the respective values:

```
cbind(gr, count = tab[id1.ij] - tab[id2.ij])
#   id1 id2 count
#1    1   1     0
#2    2   1     3
#3    3   1     2
#4    4   1     3
#5    1   2     4
#6    2   2     0
#7    3   2     3
#8    4   2     3
#9    1   3     5
#10   2   3     5
#11   3   3     0
#12   4   3     4
#13   1   4     5
#14   2   4     4
#15   3   4     3
#16   4   4     0
```

Of course, if we do not need the full grid of values, we can set:

```
gr = unique(df)
```

which results in:

```
#   id1 id2 count
#1    1   2     4
#3    1   3     5
#4    1   4     5
#5    2   1     3
#6    2   3     5
#7    2   4     4
#8    3   1     2
#9    3   4     3
#10   4   2     3
#11   4   1     3
```

Comment: Yeah absolutely huge on the speed/efficiency for this one. I really appreciate the answer here, works like a charm in <10 seconds.

Comment: @cebola : Glad you've found it helpful. I had a concern on the memory requirements of constructing the `table`, at start, but all good. Nonetheless, the first object can be constructed as a "sparseMatrix", if necessary, which requires less memory than `table`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks also for the tip on SparseMatrix! I do have a follow up, but if it's not appropriate to ask here let me know. For another part of an analysis I'd like to including a 'grouping variable'. I.e. only count the times A occurs without B if B also isn't included within, let's say, a given timestamp (even if B is in a different row from A). Other than creating matrices for each grouping variable, I wasn't sure how to adapt your answer here.

Comment: @cebola : Hm, as I understand in such a case, you basically need to `table` by group and not by row (since, basically in your orginal example, a row is essentially a different group)? I.e. begin with something like `crossprod(table(rep(df$group, 2), c(df$id1, df$id2)))`?

Comment: Got it I see, I'll need to play around with the crossprod function a bit but again appreciate the suggestion.